# Single-line JSON code folding style in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to configure VSC to fold JSON so that folded sections collapse to one line? The only options I see are "indentation" and "auto", where auto folds based on syntax for supported languages.  But auto behaves like indentation, annoyingly putting the opening and closing of a code block on separate lines. I want it to behave like IntelliJ, putting the opening and closing on the same line.

VSC v1.56.0:
[image: fold1]

PyCharm v2021.1.1:
[image: fold2]